# SQL Server 2005 - Good SQL to create a data dictionary

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have to create a data dictionary in an existing database for all user tables within that database in SQL Server 2005.

Does anyone have a good piece of sql to use for this purpose.   I am intending to add comments in myself after I have the details of the tables and columns.

Comment: What do you mean by 'data dictionary'?

Comment: The data dictionary is the metadata about the DB and the objects it contains (e.g., names and attributes for each table).

Comment: Yes, that would be correct I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the exact sql, but you will need to query the systables and syscolumns tables, which have all of the information you need to create the data dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "[information schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)" views.  Here are 2 of the most useful views:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this yourself, you could take a look at some SQL Server documentation tools/scripts:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1250

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Doc/index.htm

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1499

Answer (score 0):

https://www.csvreader.com/posts/data_dictionary.php

```
SELECT
    d.[primary key],
    d.[foreign key],
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(d.[column]) = 0 THEN d.[table]
        ELSE ''
    END AS [table],
    d.[column],
    CAST(d.[description] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [description],
    d.[data type],
    d.nullable,
    d.[identity],
    d.[default]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            '' AS [primary key],
            '' AS [foreign key],
            s.[name] AS [schema],
            CASE
                WHEN s.[name] = 'dbo' THEN t.[name]
                ELSE s.[name] + '.' + t.[name]
            END AS [table],
            '' AS [column],
            ISNULL(RTRIM(CAST(ep.[value] AS NVARCHAR(4000))), '') AS [description],
            '' AS [data type],
            '' AS nullable,
            '' AS [identity],
            '' AS [default],
            NULL AS column_id
        FROM
            sys.tables t

                INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON
                    s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]

                -- get description of table, if available
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties ep ON
                    ep.major_id = t.[object_id] AND
                    ep.minor_id = 0 AND
                    ep.name = 'MS_Description' AND
                    ep.class = 1
        WHERE
            t.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
            NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM
                    sys.extended_properties ms
                WHERE
                    ms.major_id = t.[object_id] AND
                    ms.minor_id = 0 AND
                    ms.class = 1 AND
                    ms.[name] = 'microsoft_database_tools_support'
            )

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN pk.column_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'PK'
                ELSE ''
            END AS [primary key],
            CASE
                WHEN fk.primary_table IS NOT NULL
                    THEN fk.primary_table + '.' + fk.primary_column
                ELSE ''
            END AS [foreign key],
            s.[name] AS [schema],
            CASE
                WHEN s.[name] = 'dbo' THEN t.[name]
                ELSE s.[name] + '.' + t.[name]
            END AS [table],
            c.[name] AS [column],
            ISNULL(RTRIM(CAST(ep.[value] AS NVARCHAR(4000))), '') AS [description],
            CASE
                WHEN uty.[name] IS NOT NULL THEN uty.[name]
                ELSE ''
            END +
                CASE
                    WHEN uty.[name] IS NOT NULL AND sty.[name] IS NOT NULL THEN '('
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE
                    WHEN sty.[name] IS NOT NULL THEN sty.[name]
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE
                    WHEN sty.[name] IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'binary', 'varbinary')
                        THEN '(' + 
                            CASE
                                WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'max'
                                ELSE 
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN sty.[name] IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar')
                                            THEN CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                                        ELSE
                                            CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                                    END
                            END
                             + ')'
                    WHEN sty.[name] IN ('numeric', 'decimal')
                        THEN '(' + 
                            CAST(c.precision AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                             + ')'
                    ELSE
                        ''
                END +
                CASE
                    WHEN uty.[name] IS NOT NULL AND sty.[name] IS NOT NULL THEN ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END AS [data type],
            CASE
                WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'Y'
                ELSE ''
            END AS nullable,
            CASE
                WHEN c.is_identity = 1 THEN 'Y'
                ELSE ''
            END AS [identity],
            ISNULL(dc.[definition], '') AS [default],
            c.column_id
        FROM
            sys.columns c
                INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON
                    t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]

                INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON
                    s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]

                -- get name of user data type
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types uty ON
                    uty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id AND
                    uty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id AND
                    c.user_type_id <> c.system_type_id

                -- get name of system data type
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types sty ON
                    sty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id AND
                    sty.user_type_id = c.system_type_id

                -- get description of column, if available
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties ep ON
                    ep.major_id = t.[object_id] AND
                    ep.minor_id = c.column_id AND
                    ep.[name] = 'MS_Description' AND
                    ep.[class] = 1

                -- get default's code text
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.default_constraints dc ON
                    dc.parent_object_id = t.[object_id] AND
                    dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id

                -- check for inclusion in primary key
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT
                        ic.column_id,
                        i.[object_id]
                    FROM
                        sys.indexes i
                            INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON
                                ic.index_id = i.index_id AND
                                ic.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
                    WHERE
                        i.is_primary_key = 1
                ) pk ON
                    pk.column_id = c.column_id AND
                    pk.[object_id] = t.[object_id]

                -- check for inclusion in foreign key
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT
                        CASE
                            WHEN s.[name] = 'dbo' THEN pk.[name]
                            ELSE s.[name] + '.' + pk.[name]
                        END AS primary_table,
                        pkc.[name] as primary_column,
                        fkc.parent_object_id,
                        fkc.parent_column_id
                    FROM
                        sys.foreign_keys fk
                            INNER JOIN sys.tables pk ON
                                fk.referenced_object_id = pk.[object_id]
                            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON
                                s.[schema_id] = pk.[schema_id]
                            INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON
                                fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id] AND
                                fkc.referenced_object_id = pk.[object_id]
                            INNER JOIN sys.columns pkc ON
                                pkc.[object_id] = pk.[object_id] AND
                                pkc.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
                ) fk ON
                    fk.parent_object_id = t.[object_id] AND
                    fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
        WHERE
            t.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
            NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM
                    sys.extended_properties ms
                WHERE
                    ms.major_id = t.[object_id] AND
                    ms.minor_id = 0 AND
                    ms.class = 1 AND
                    ms.[name] = 'microsoft_database_tools_support'
            )
    ) d
ORDER BY
    d.[schema],
    d.[table],
    d.column_id;
```